# SQL - GROUP and WHERE ERROR

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

[WRONG OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf3bY.png)

Week 1 to Week 52
Count all the reports for each week
Count all the targets for each week

[EDITED]

I started from basics and scratch.

```
CREATE TABLE Records
    ([Dates] DATE, [Week] INTEGER, [dayOfWeek] varchar(10), [report] INTEGER)
;

INSERT INTO Records
    ([Dates], [Week], [dayOfWeek], [report] )
VALUES
    ('02/01/2017', '1', 'Monday', '1'),
    ('03/01/2017', '1', 'Tuesday', '2'),
    ('04/01/2017', '1', 'Wednesday', '2'),
    ('05/01/2017', '1', 'Thursday', '5'),
    ('06/01/2017', '1', 'Friday', '1')
;
```

QUERY

```
SELECT Week, dayOfWeek, COUNT(report) AS TotalReports
FROM Records
GROUP BY Records.Week, Records.dayOfWeek
```

Comment: The sample data you have provided does not match the query.  That makes it really hard to understand what you want to do.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff   Hi, I have re-edited my image and post.   I generate date from start of 2017 to end of the month in 2018.      I run a query and I would like the query to run through all my records in the table to count the reports between every Monday to Friday and classify that as the Week 1, 2, 3, etc.

Comment: Your GROUP BY column list should be the same as non-aggregated  column list in SELECT

Comment: Agreed with @Serg, so it is interesting SQL Server did not err on that message! Also, SQL is missing a comma. Please post a compilable, reproducible example with no screenshots.

Comment: @Parfait  I have simplified my whole sql as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you want to SUM() rather than COUNT().  COUNT() will return the number of rows, SUM() will add-up the values contained in the column.

```
SELECT Week, dayOfWeek, SUM(report) AS TotalReports
FROM Records
GROUP BY Week, dayOfWeek
```